# Eating Matzah of Tevel or Heqdesh

Tags: halacha, passover, matzah

As DoubleAA has reminded me, the Mishna in Pesachim 2:5 forbids the usage of matzah that is tevel or heqdesh on the evening of Pesach. In his commentary on Nedarim 2:2, however, the Bartenura appears to suggest that it is merely a mitzvah that comes from an 'aveirah. As none of the super-commentaries appear to have a problem with this, how best might one understand that passage in the Bartenura?

For context, the mishna there says that one may make a vow that forbids him from utilising his sukkah, waving the four species and laying tefillin, but may not make an oath that prevents him from doing so (אמר: קונם סוכה שאני עושה, לולב שאני נוטל, תפלין שאני מניח - בנדרים אסור, בשבועות מותר שאין משבעין לעבור על המצות). Obviously, saying that one *may* vow to abstain from such things doesn't mean that one is necessarily permitted to do so, but that the vow stands.

In his commentary on the Mishna, Rambam implies that one should nevertheless still sit in the sukkah, wave the four species and lay tefillin, but that this would then obligate him to bring a qorban. Rav Ovadiah of Bertinoro explains similarly, and notes that it would be accounted a mitzvah that comes from an 'aveirah. To my confusion, the Bartinura then likens it to somebody who only has matzah of tevel or heqdesh on the evening of Pesach.

Seeing as the mishna in Pesachim forbids one from utilising such matzah at all, why would the Bartenura suggest that it is similar to somebody who makes a vow that precludes him from using the sukkah, and who then uses it and brings a qorban?

Comment: [Mishna Pesachim 2:5](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%94) so your Bartinura is even more odd.

Comment: Thank you! That then makes this a question on the Bartenura, and not on the halakha... I don't know if I can edit that into it - it's a whole other question. Should I delete it, or should I rephrase it and let you just post this as an answer?

Comment: Whatever you like. Perhaps change this into just asking about tevel/hekdesh matza without all the background, and then ask a new question referencing this as a question on the Bartinura? Just an idea

Comment: Thanks, @DoubleAA; I decided to simply rephrase the question in accordance with the new information. Feel free to delete these comments if you think that would be appropriate.

Comment: See P'sachim 35b, which explains that the tevel referred to in the mishna is tevel mid'rabbanan (e.g. from an atzitz she'eino nakuv), from which one is yotzei b'di'avad (see Rashi 35b, s.v. *t'vul mid'rabbanan*). The hekdesh referred to is hekdesh that was redeemed al gabei karaka, which I guess perhaps R' Ovadia miBartenura holds is not fully hekdesh. Alternatively, maybe he used the expression "shel tevel oh shel hekdesh" but only meant referring to "shel tevel".

Comment: @Fred The Bavli is saying that because _real_ hekdesh or tevel is obviously no good. It gives a weaker example so the Mishna can teach a Chiddush.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes, but in the case of tevel at least, Rashi interprets the gemara as saying (incidentally to the point you mentioned) that the mishna only meant to say it is assur, not that you are literally not yotzei.

Comment: BTW @ShimonbM Here is the relevant Rambam http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=2264

Comment: I don't understand the first paragraph. It's worded as if it's your main question, but all it asks is an apparent contradiction between saying something is forbidden and saying it's a _mitzva habaa baavera_. That's neither (a) obviously a contradiction (maybe performing a _mitzva habaa baavera_ is forbidden) nor (b) consistent AFAICT with the question in your last paragraph.

Comment: @msh210 - That is true... But I'm not sure how best to edit it now without totally messing it up. It is *possible* that the Bartenura is not agreeing with the Rambam, and that he also thinks it is forbidden to sit in a sukkah if you have made a vow that you wouldn't do so. My question presupposes that he doesn't think that; can an argument be made that he does?

Comment: Perhaps the fact that he always follows the _Rambam_? `:-)` Seriously, though, isn't there a clear question on the _Rav_ in that he likens the _neder_ case to the _tevel_ case, at the same time giving a different rule for the former than another _mishna_ does for the latter? Why do you need to worry about whether its status is _mitzva habaa baavera_?

Comment: @msh210 - I included that line because he mentions it in the same section, and I imagine that it would be relevant to an understanding of where he's coming from. Maybe somebody knows if, elsewhere, he makes clear what his opinions are about a mitzvah that comes from an 'aveirah?